# FW1 Service call

Tags: coldfusion, fw1

Can someone explain how the FW1 service call works? As I read the section from the manual below. I thought the following should work.

See: https://github.com/seancorfield/fw1/wiki/Reference-Manual

> A service method is passed a collection of named arguments, based on whatever is in the request context after the controller methods have executed (i.e., after before(), startItem() and item() ). A service method may return a result, which is placed into the request context by FW/1. By default, FW/1 1.x stores the result of the (initial) service method call in rc.data.

controller/comparables.cfc

```
component { 
    public any function init( fw ) {
        variables.fw = fw;
        return this;
    }
    
    
    public void function autocomplete( rc ) {
        // queue up a specific service (comparables.autocomplete) with named result (autocomplete)
        var args = StructNew();
        StructInsert( args, "table", "The Table" );
        StructInsert( args, "column", "The Column" );
        variables.fw.service( 'comparables.autocomplete', 'autocomplete', args );
    }
}
```

service/comparables.cfc

```
component { 
    public any function autocomplete( string table, string column, string term ) {      
        return "not yet implemented #table# #column# #term#";
    }
}
```

The following view displays rc.autocomplete = "not yet implemented"

views/comparables/autocomplete.cfm

```
<cfdump var="#variables.rc#" >
```

Comment: `suppressImplicitService` is set to `true` by default in v2, therefore you should really invoke your own service(s) and put the results in `rc` yourself.  See: https://github.com/seancorfield/fw1/wiki/Developing-Applications-Manual

Comment: Henry, the call to service() in the controller is doing this, placing the result in rc.autocomplete. suppressImplicitService=true means the service isn't automatically called and placed in rc.data, which was the 1.x behavior.

Comment: The code looks correct to me, assuming that rc.term is defined before the service call. What do you see when you dump the arguments scope from within the service function?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe that it was getting cached. When I did a ?reload=true things improved and started working. I'll post any corrections when I get back to work tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able figure out how it all fits together. 
The following service call would return a value immediately whereas the above would not be called until the controller method has finished.

```
comp_serv = CreateObject("component","services.comparables");
rc.comparables = comp_serv.autocomplete( "table","colum","term" );
```